# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to List

Tags: java

I have only this, but my compiler says:Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList to List
So what is the problem can anyone tell me ? I'm using Elipse Java EE IDE.

```
import java.awt.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List list = new ArrayList();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

incorrect import, it has to be `java.util.List`.

Answer (score 5):

You've imported `java.awt.List`, which is the list control in the AWT package, instead of `java.util.List`, which is the collections class representing a list of elements.  Thus Java thinks you're converting from a logical array list of values into a widget, which doesn't make any sense.

Changing the import line to

```
import java.util.List;
```

should fix this, as would writing

```
java.util.List list = new ArrayList();
```

to explicitly indicate that you want a collection.

That said, you should also be using generics here.  Using raw collections types has long been deprecated.  The best answer is to write something like

```
List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You need to import `java.util.List` instead of `java.awt.List`.

You might also want to use type parameters instead of raw types. For instance, if the list was going to hold `String` values:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

or, prior to Java 7:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Actually you have a redundant type argument by specifying String twice. Since you have List<String> you can follow it with ArrayList<>()

Comment: @Gabe - That's true; but prior to Java 7, the second `String` was required. Old habits die hard. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `java.util.ArrayList` extends `java.util.List`, not `java.awt.List`. You are importing the wrong class:

```
import java.awt.List;
```

vs.

```
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 1):

As told by others its an import error. Since you are using Eclipse EDE if there is an error keep the cursor in that place and press `Ctrl + 1`, it will show suggestions for you which might help you in fixing the errors.